# Is it possible to put the current date and time inside a mat-form-field?

Tags: angular, typescript, input, time, mat-form-field

I have a mat-form-field where I want the current time to be displayed inside an input field. I was able to add it inside but I'm having problem with the styling.
Here is the line of code:

```
<mat-label>Filing Time:</mat-label><br>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-1">
                <input
                  matInput
                  formControlName="filingTime"
                  readonly
                  required
                />
                {{ filingDate | date: 'HH:mm:ss' }}
              </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually adding that "inside" your input, it's actually oustide, if what you are looking to achieve is auto filling the input, then you need to use `value` property on `<input/>` but this ofcourse would cause a problem as that you can not use the `date pipe` inside the `value` property, therefore, you will have to use `ngModel` which will change your approach since that you're using the `Reactive Forms` approach, but you would figure this out easily either by using the
`standalone = true` for your `ngModel` (**that's if you don't want this field to appear in your `form`**), Or you can keep the `name` property instead of `formControlName` and that would do too (**That's if you wan the field to appear in your `form`**), the basic implementation would go something like this:

```
<mat-label>Filing Time:</mat-label><br>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-1">
  <input matInput [ngModel]="filingDate | date: 'HH:MM:SS'" />
</mat-form-field>
```

I can update this answer to suit your case after looking to some more code in the rest of your template, and your `component class`.

Hope this helped.